# Create list with all combination of dictionaries, where key only appears once

Tags: python, python-itertools

I tried different approaces with itertools, but just can't figure it out.

I need to find different combinations of dictionaries:

```
letters = ['a','b','c']

combinations = []
for i in range(3):
    for t in letters:
        one_combi = {str(t):i}
        combinations.append(one_combi)
```

Now have a list of dictionaries {letter:number}
Now I need to create a list of combinations where the key (letter) only appear once.

Expected output looks something like this:

```
[{'a':0,'b':0,'c':0},
{'a':1,'b':0,'c':0},
{'a':1,'b':1,'c':0},
{'a':1,'b':1,'c':1},
{'a':2,'b':0,'c':0},
...
{'a':2,'b':2,'c':2}]
```

Would be great if someone can help me out on this one!

Answer (score 1):

You can generate all combinations of integers from a range derived from the length of the input, and then use `zip`:

```
letters = ['a','b','c']
def combos(d, c = []):
  if len(c) == len(d):
     yield dict(zip(letters, c))
  else:
     for i in d:
        yield from combos(d, c+[i])

print(list(combos(range(len(letters))))
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, 
{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}, 
{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 2}, 
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 0}, 
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, 
...
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product

lst = []
for a, b, c in product([0, 1, 2], repeat=3):
  lst.append({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c})
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0},
{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 1},
{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 2},
{'a': 0, 'b':1, 'c': 0},
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 1},
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2},
{'a': 0, 'b': 2, 'c': 0},
{'a': 0, 'b': 2, 'c': 1},...
```

**Update**

We can compact everything into a single line using list comprehension.

```
letters = ['a','b','c']
lst = [dict(zip(letters, x)) for x in product(range(len(letters)), repeat=len(letters))]
print(lst)
```

Comment: Could even make this a list comprehension, eh?

Comment: Looks good! Is there a way to use a list for a, b, c? I actualy got a lot more keys to combine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. One follow up for efficiency purposes. is it possible to use a dict instead of a list, with the max value for the range in product? So {'a':2,'b':6,'c':4}, where in the combinations, 'a' won't go higher than 2, and 'b' to 6?